# Print Driver is not working for HP4250n

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, drivers, printing, hplip

Since "upgrading" from Ubuntu version 11.10 to 12.4 on my T60, I can't get my HP 4250n laser printer to function. I get memory overrun messages printed on the printer instead. This never happened with 11.10. The printer functions properly using two XP machines (a T42 and another T60) and also using a Windows 7 machine (a new HP laptop). I've see other issues also.

Comment: What version of **HPLIP** are you currently using?  And, have you updated the stub-driver (loaded to HP printer) since the upgrade to **12.04**?

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the driver and reinstalling. I have noticed that upgrade ubuntu can cause driver & program problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try some other similar driver. It worked for me several times. 
Also you can check on this page, there is solution for allmoest all printer :
 [Printers and Linux - How to find drivers, install, setup | Linux migration tutorials](http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Its important that you explain your affliation with this link - if its your blog then say so.